# Is there a way to attack STARTTLS + certificate pinning probed from multiple places?

Tags: tls, email, pgp, smtp, certificate-pinning

I just had this discussion on IRC and I have to admit I did not understand why other users were not convinced this would be enough... Let's say I would like to protect e-mails sent out from my mailserver, even at the cost of being incompatible with servers not supporting STARTTLS. By "protect" I mean maintaining their confidentiality and integrity while assuming that the adversary can perform active attacks on the majority of Internet (but would prefer to stay undetected).

The solution I thought of is the following: configure your mail server so that when an outgoing e-mail is sent, I enforce STARTTLS and use e.g. Tor to connect through multiple different countries in order to verify the certificate I would pin in the next session. If the certificate does not match, the e-mail doesn't get sent.

I understand the main problems with the solution vs PGP - it's not visible to the user, it doesn't work across ends and it breaks compatibility. But assuming that this was actually used on the whole Internet, would it be possible to pull attack against this scheme?

Answer (score 1):

What attacks do you want to prevent? If a malicious system administrator (or anybody/any agency forcing him to be one) is contained in the list, you're out of luck without end-to-end encryption, no matter what fancy validation schemes you apply.

Regarding your approach: as I understand, it is absed on the idea that nobody will be able to control different routes from different countries (out of different Tor exit nodes) to the other mail server. This is not necessary for an attacker -- he only needs to be in control of the other mail server's uplink to be man in the middle to *all* those verifications at once.

Comment: I agree that this is one of the problems. On the other hand, he also needs to intercept the very first session or the certificate would be pinned.

Comment: Certificates are exchanged over time. Who will verify if a certificate changed for valid reasons?

Comment: Nothing other than CRL comes to my head.

Answer (score 1):

> configure your mail server so that when an outgoing e-mail is sent, I enforce STARTTLS ... verify the certificate I would pin in the next session. If the certificate does not match, the e-mail doesn't get sent.

There are several problems:

- The mail is delivered in multiple hops, e.g. from your mail client to your mail server from their to the mail server of the  client, either directly or with some more mail servers in between. On each of the hops in between the mail is available in plain text since encryption is done only for the transport between the hops.
- You can control and secure only the connection from your mail server to the next hop.
- Even if you verify the certificate of the server correctly you can still not be sure that you are talking to the correct server. Which servers are responsible for a domain are detected with DNS lookups for the MX records and these lookups can be spoofed unless their are protected by DNSSec themselves. So you might get the result that `attacker.example.com` is the responsible mail server for `*@goodguy.example.com`, connect to it and verify that the certificates matches `attacker.example.com`.
- And of course certificates might change without revoking the previous certificate, so you get false alarms and finally delivery errors.